# Факты о чем-то или чего-то?

Tags: согласование

Сейчас писала вопрос о словах на букву Ы, и меня заклинило)))) Как правильно сказать: факты о чем-то? Факты чего-то? Факты в чем-то? Там речь шла об "интересных фактах о русском языке" (или "русского языка"? Или "в русском языке"?)
Факты, они факты и есть, но как их соотнести с чем-то?
Скорее всего, я бы и не задумалась, но бывает, что клинит на чем-то простом.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Факт чего-то" заключает в себе это что-то, например какое-то событие. "Факт кораблекрушения (= то, что кораблекрушение произошло) подчёркивает опасность этих рифов."

"Факты о чём-то" - дополнительные хорошо проверенные сведения об этом, обычно связанные с реальными событиями, а не представлениями о них.

"Факты о русском языке", в принципе, могут быть связаны с какими-то внешними событиями, напр. изменившими употребление слов.

Выражение "факты русского языка" сложно к чему-то отнести, поскольку то, что в содержании самого языка, нематериально, а факты - принадлежность реального мира. Назвать что-либо фактом равносильно утверждению, что "это" было или есть на самом деле, а не только в мире идей и представлений.

"Факт в чём-то" - встречается преимущественно в риторических оборотах. "Но факт в том... = имеет место ещё и такое (= на самом деле для окончательного вывода важно именно это, а не то, о чём мы сейчас говорим; = реальность такова)."

"В русском языке" - лучше сказать без "фактов", напр. "интересные моменты в русском языке".

Comment: >"Факт чего-то..." 
>"Факты о чём-то..." 
>"Факты о русском языке...",   
  
Очень странная классификация. А почему не наоборот? "Факты о кораблекрушении"?

Comment: Это о том, в каких случаях допустимо упоминание "фактов" с тем или иным предлогом из упомянутых в вопросе.

Comment: Вот её-то, вашей классификации, я и не понял.

Comment: У меня здесь нет классификации, это перечисление принципиально разных случаев, затронутых в вопросе или в его заголовке. "Кораблекрушение" приведено для корректного случая "факт чего-то(события)". "Факты русского языка" (видимо, у вас возник вопрос, почему это отдельно), будь это выражение удачным в смысловом отношении, не несло бы в себе такого же грамматического оттенка: это не "факт произошедшего события", а "факты *из* русского языка" (формально, "имеющиеся внутри языка"). Соответственно, несмотря на тот же падеж, это нельзя классифицировать как вариант "кораблекрушения", потому отдельно.

Comment: >У меня здесь нет классификации, это перечисление принципиально разных случаев,  
Это и есть классификация. Вы же "перечисляете случаи" ради того, чтобы к одному из низ можно было отнести все подобные? Иначе такое перечисление вообще бессмысленно.   
  
Ладно, хоть горшком назови. Я не понял вашего перечисления. 

Почему я не могу сказать "Факты о кораблекрушении"?

Comment: >"Факты русского языка" (видимо, у вас возник вопрос, почему это отдельно), будь это выражение удачным в смысловом отношении, не несло бы в себе такого же грамматического оттенка: это не "факт произошедшего события", а "факты из русского языка" (формально, "имеющиеся внутри языка"). Соответственно, несмотря на тот же падеж, это нельзя классифицировать как вариант "кораблекрушения", потому отдельно.  

Ничего не понял. Какой еще "оттенок"? "Факты русского языка" это как "Факты истории", "факты жизни Пети". Не "Факты от Пети", а "Факты о Пете". И "факты кораблекрушения" - все о нем, крушении.

Comment: Классификацией я называю систематизированное расположение матерала, например, в порядке значимости. Перечислены с пояснениями только те случаи, которые есть в вопросе (в этом и состоит смысл). Вы можете сказать "факты о кораблекрушении", но зачем? Этот случай рассмотрен непосредственно на примере из вопроса ("факты о русском языке").
Какой оттенок? "Факт кораблекрушения" = событие кораблекрушения; "факты о кораблекрушении" - обстоятельства, сопутствовавшие этому событию, подробности о нём и т.п. Это разные вещи.

Comment: "Факты (из) жизни" Пети: родился, учился, занимался ещё чем-то, оставил умные труды.
"Факты о жизни" Пети: Петя написал такую книгу, что прочитавший её правнук Че Гевары стал известным мореплавателем.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны оба варианта. 
Есть некоторые смысловые и стилистические отличия.

Факты чего? - обычно в отношении общих явлений: факты пьянства, использования оружия, международного сотрудничества. 
Факты о чем? - о конкретных вещах: факты о кошках, о космосе, о жизни индейцев Патагонии.

В вашем случае, думаю, *"интересные факты о русском языке"* вполне допустимо.

"Факты в языке" - это что-то о совсем другом. *"А где факты?" - "А факты - в языке".*
Тогда уж лучше *"факты из языка"*. ))) Как *"факты из истории (допустим) российского флота".*

Answer (score 0):

Слово "факты" здесь употреблено неудачно. Просто "интересное в русском языке" или что-то в этом роде.

Если уж нужны "факты", то они "в языке". Но коряво.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно говорят: интересные факты о русском языке, **выражение "факты русского языка" не используется.** Но можно сказать: факты русской истории, факт кораблекрушения.

Предмет может быть фактом (факт кораблекрушения), а может состоять из фактов (факты истории).

Язык тоже может быть фактом, например, язык как факт иноязычной культуры. Но язык не состоит из фактов, как история, поэтому нельзя сказать "факты русского языка". Можно описать языковые явления, но это уже будут "факты о русском языке".